# Cannot cast HashMap returned object to Arraylist

Tags: java, casting

I am running this code on the Tomcat server as a Java application.

```
if(levelMap.get(bssid_a) == null)
    continue;
ArrayList<String> levels_a = new ArrayList<String>();
levels_a = (ArrayList<String>)levelMap.get(bssid_a);
```

where levelMap is a hashmap defines as:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

The same code is working in my Android application, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

The original function (without type casting, but gives me the same error):

```
    public EDistance[] getLocation(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap) {

        HashMap<String, CrossProduct> crossProductList_local = new HashMap<String, CrossProduct>();

        LinkedHashSet<String> localList = (LinkedHashSet<String>) globalList.clone();

        Iterator<String> cpItera = localList.iterator();
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Iterator<String> levelIter = levelMap.keySet().iterator();
        // try {

        while (cpItera.hasNext()) {

            String ssids[] = cpItera.next().split(",");
            String bssid_a = ssids[0];

            if(levelMap.get(bssid_a) == null)
                continue;
            //ArrayList<String> levels_a = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> levels_a = levelMap.get(bssid_a);
            double meanA = mean(levels_a, sampleSize, defaultLevel);

            // Iterator<String> cpIterb = localList.iterator();
            //
            // while(cpIterb.hasNext())
            // {

            String bssid_b = ssids[1];
            // if(bssid_a.equals(bssid_b))
            // continue;
            if(levelMap.get(bssid_b) == null)
                continue;
            //ArrayList<String> levels_b = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> levels_b = levelMap.get(bssid_b);
            double meanB = mean(levels_b, sampleSize, defaultLevel);
............
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Failed to invoke method distance in class com.fingerprint.core.Calculate: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method distance in class com.fingerprint.core.Calculate: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet.doPost(XmlRpcServlet.java:196)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.fingerprint.location.HyperbolicEuclideanDistance.getLocation(HyperbolicEuclideanDistance.java:235)
    at com.fingerprint.core.Calculate.distance(Calculate.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    ... 24 more
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.fingerprint.location.HyperbolicEuclideanDistance.getLocation(HyperbolicEuclideanDistance.java:235)
    at com.fingerprint.core.Calculate.distance(Calculate.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet.doPost(XmlRpcServlet.java:196)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code calling the XMlRPC method:

```
public String getLocationXMLRPC(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap, String mapFile) {

    try {
        XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://172.28.184.222:8080/LocationService/xmlrpc");

        Object[] params = new Object[]{levelMap, mapFile};
        //EDistance retura[] = (EDistance[]) client.callEx("Calculate.distance", params);
        String result = (String) client.callEx("Calculate.distance", params);
        return result;

    } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The XMLRPC method that calls the erroneous function:

```
public String distance(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap, String mapFile)
{
    if(dist == null){
        dist = new HyperbolicEuclideanDistance(mapFile, 3, -130,
                false, "fake.txt");
        System.out.println("New Class created!");
    }
    EDistance[] result =  dist.getLocation(levelMap);

    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();

    for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (result[j] != null)
            build.append(j + ") " + result[j] + "\n");
    }
    return build.toString(); 

}
```

The code that calls the server:

```
public String getLocationXMLRPC(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap, String mapFile) {

    try {
        XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://172.28.184.222:8080/LocationService/xmlrpc");


        String result = (String) client.call("Calculate.distance", levelMap, mapFile);
        return result;

    } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: levelMap appears to be a `HashMap<String, Object[]>` not a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. The JVM is not wrong in this situation, but somehow your understanding of your code must be. The reason is buried in code not shown.

Comment: Please show us, what you put in `levelMap`. That is the cause for the `ClassCastException`. Besides it is not necessary to initialize `levels_a` with an empty `ArrayList<String>`, if you overwrite it at once. And: You don't have to cast, if levelMap is really declared as you already showed.

Comment: this is the function signature where this code is
`public EDistance[] getLocation(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> levelMap) {`

Comment: @ishan If that is the case, you don't need a cast at all. Show the whole method.

Comment: I have a String as the key and a list of strings in an ArrayList as the value. @Arne I am not exactly sure what you are asking. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: @ishan if levelMap really is a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` then you should be able to write `ArrayList<String> levels_a = levelMap.get(bssid_a);`. Try that and whatever compilation error you get should help you find the issue.

Comment: Looking at your edit, it seems impossible that you get that error. That is weird...

Comment: What is a non-generic HashMap. I am using XMLRPC to get the HashMap form the object which I pass to this function. I have added the Stacktrace too if that makes it more clear.

Comment: @ishan we need to see the XMLRPC call, its bindingt etc. It's obvious that there is no `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` in `levelMap`. The cause for this is the way you call the method.

Comment: @ishan in `getLocationXMLRPC` the parameter is already declared as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. How do you call this method?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `distance` must be a method of some class `Calculate` - if that's not an alias - and is called inside the XMLRPC server. The invalid parameter is set up at the client side.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue during marshalling/unmarshalling ? Is XMLRPCClient able of keeping nested class/generics like that ? (I don't know at all this class)

Comment: @Arne I have added the code that calls this function.

Comment: @ishan you posted the `getLocationXMLRPC` method again. We need to see the way you *call* it. And, as cporte mentioned two comments above, it may also be that XMLRPC does not marshal such types at all. So you should check the documentation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ws-xmlrpc XMLRPC Data-Types](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html) a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`is not a directly supported parameter type.

From the exception stacktrace you posted one can see that a `HashMap<String, Object>` made it along the wire to your XMLRPC server. That's obvious as the server needs to invoke the `distance` method using Java reflection. Doing that, a exception would occur if the parameter is not a HashMap at least. Instead the exception in your trace happens, when retrieving an object from that map. There is a invisible type check at runtime when retrieving and assigning an element from `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, and that check fails with the exception you have.

Thus it may be a marshalling problem for your XMLRPC library to pass your parameters. So, as `Map<String, List<String>>` according to the above documentation should be a valid parameter type though, try to change the `distance` method's and their callees parameters to that and try again.

If that also fails, think about passing the parameters in another more flat and simple structure.

Comment: Thanks. I flattened the structure by converting the arraylist to a csv string and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue myself. It appears that ws-xmlrpc converts a List inside another structure to an array, even if the function parameter is specified as a List. So Map[String,List[String]] is converted to Map[String,Object] with Object being an array of String.  I solved this by handling the incoming List as an array. In some cases I used instanceof to distinguish between array and List.